# Typescript - Type Assertion on Non-Required Values

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rest, axios, undefined

This is more to validate the correct way of handling things.

I'm using Vue front-end with Typescript, posting data to an API through axios.

I have reactive objects like:

```js
const payload = reactive({
  name: '',
  religion: undefined as string | undefined
  gender: undefined as string | undefined
})
```

A rather simple example, however, seeing as the religion and gender fields are not required to be in the payload unless set when posted to the API, they're by default set to undefined, which then are filtered out when  posted.

Is this the correct way of handling such scenarios?

Should I handle this in a better way?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to write a type that models your data as a first step. You can use the `foo?: SomeType` syntax to declare a property as optional.

```
interface MyCoolThing {
    name: string,
    religion?: string
    gender?: string
}
```

Now you can use that whole type to enforce this:

```
const payload = reactive({
  name: '',
  religion: undefined,
  gender: undefined,
} as MyCoolThing)
```

But then you can do better. `reactive` is a generic function where the generic type parameter is the type of its first argument. So you can just explicitly pass that type:

```
const payload = reactive<MyCoolThing>({
  name: '',
  religion: undefined,
  gender: undefined,
})
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzlApgQwMY2ANxXAXzgDMoIQ4ByHAVxUoCgHgA7GFKYzfAWQE8AwhAgAbACoALVgHNEDOArgs0IFAC44AZxhQZAGnmLUI4NOAQWAfg3bdLaYYXSULACYdrWnTIYEmGC204MDQ+EQg0VzgAXmR0LFwUAB5+IVFJGQA+AAoEQ2VVDUpKAwVjU3MWDRo3FGJWFFdSuGdaqGra+pZGgwIASiA)